# Calling first button on confirm of second button in javascript isn't working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have two buttons in my html page and when someone clicks Generate button I want to save my document (the same thing save button is doing) if ok is clicked otherwise I do not want to do anything.

Js code 
                    $("#save-application").trigger("click");

I also tried to use

```
  document.getElementById('save-application').click();
```

and

```
   $('#save-application').click();
```

But it isnt working.So basically I want to call my save button.Any suggestions on this?

I did tried

```
          if (check == true) {    
                $("#form").submit();
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
```

but form doesn't get saved

Comment: Your code right now has $("save-application") without the `#` indicating it's an id field..is that a typo when asking this question or is that a problem in your code?

Comment: I tried both with # and without #.Doesn't work either way

Comment: Assuming you're trying to submit the form, [why not try to do it manually?](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Comment: You mean something like  $("#save-application").submit();  I did tried this one too.It didnt work

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed `#` while querying by id `$("#save-application").click();`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using trigger , you can create separate function for save functionality, 
html code :

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" id="save-application" onclick="saveApplication();"/>
```

js code :

```
function saveApplication(){
    //logic here
}
```

and then call saveApplication() instead of $("save-application").trigger("click");

Comment: Actually from the Generate button, I want to call the save button, so basically from Javascript I have to find a way to call the save-application.

Answer (score 0):

So I'd do something like this on your input

```
<input id="save-application" type="submit" value="Save" onclick="saveApplication()"/>
```

Then modify your javascript to something like this:

```
function saveApplication() {
        if (isChanged == true ) {                
            var check = confirm("Would you like to to save your changes and have a document generated?");
            if (check == true) {
                $("#save-application").trigger("click");                    
                return true;
            }
            else { return false; }
        } else {
            return undefined;
        }    
 }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Actually on the second button click which is Generate, I want to SAVE. And for me, $("#save-application").trigger("click");  is not working